# RequireJS doesn't work, not load library?

Tags: javascript, performance, requirejs, libraries, kdtree

It is the first time I use `RequireJS` and I don't know why it doesn't work...
I have a file `example.js` inside `Folder A`.
In the same folder I have 2 other folders that are libraries.

```
geokdbush
kdbush
```

In my file I add this code (hoping to add libraries):

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    kdbush: 'kdbush',
    geokdbush: 'geokdbush'
  } 
});
```

And inside function where I should to use libraries I add this:

```
require(['kdbush', 'geokdbush'], function(kdbush,geokdbush) {
    //code
});
```

But there are two errors: `Error: Script error for "kdbush"` and `Error: Script error for "geokdbush"`.

I don't know where the problem is in my code. These libraries are used to create K-D tree:
[Reverse geocoding with big array is fastest way? - javascript and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494643/reverse-geocoding-with-big-array-is-fastest-way-javascript-and-performance/49542182?noredirect=1#comment86123448_49542182)

Comment: You're supposed to actually include a file, e.g. `require(['kdbush/example'], function  (exampleModule) { ... })`

Comment: can you write ad answer with more code? how you can see i'm not very good programmer :P

Comment: @DominicTobias please help me :(